# Slow mysql performance

Tags: mysql, innodb

few days ago my mysql is very slow and some sql queries don't work anymore, I dont know from where come this problem.

OS: Centos

MySQL: 5.7 - InnoDB

MySQL -V: 
`mysql  Ver 14.14 Distrib 5.7.28, for Linux (x86_64) using  EditLine wrapper`

Its my query

```
SELECT 
  BTCountry.id,
  BTCountry.name,
  BTCountry.code,
  BTCountry.last_data_from,
  BTCountry.year_last_data_from AS current_year,
  (SELECT 
    SUM(cantidad) AS subCount 
  FROM
    `krakente_marketpins`.`bt_countries` AS `subBTCountry` 
    INNER JOIN `krakente_marketpins`.`bus_trucks` AS `subBusTruck` 
      ON (
        `subBusTruck`.`pais_mercado_id` = `subBTCountry`.`id`
      ) 
  WHERE `subBusTruck`.`pais_mercado_id` = `BTCountry`.`id` 
    AND `subBusTruck`.`year_data_from` = 
      `subBTCountry`.`year_last_data_from`

    AND `subBusTruck`.month_data_from <= `subBTCountry`.`month_last_data_from`) AS ytd,
  (SELECT 
    SUM(cantidad) AS subCount 
  FROM
    `krakente_marketpins`.`bt_countries` AS `subBTCountry` 
    INNER JOIN `krakente_marketpins`.`bus_trucks` AS `subBusTruck` 
      ON (
        `subBusTruck`.`pais_mercado_id` = `subBTCountry`.`id`
      ) 
  WHERE `subBusTruck`.`pais_mercado_id` = `BTCountry`.`id` 
    AND `subBusTruck`.`year_data_from` = `subBTCountry`.`year_last_data_from` - 1 
    AND `subBusTruck`.`month_data_from` <= `subBTCountry`.`month_last_data_from`) AS last_year 
FROM
  bt_countries AS BTCountry 
  INNER JOIN `krakente_marketpins`.`bus_trucks` AS `BusTruck` 
    ON (
      `BusTruck`.`pais_mercado_id` = `BTCountry`.`id`
    ) 
WHERE `pais_mercado_id` IN (
    '1',
    '2',
    '3',
    '4',
    '5',
    '6',
    '7',
    '8',
    '9',
    '10',
    '11',
    '12'
  ) 
  AND mercado_id = ('1') 
GROUP BY `BTCountry`.`id` 
ORDER BY `ytd` DESC
```

I know this query can be optimized but i need know why my mysql is working bad now.

I used mysqltuner to get recommendations but without luck.
its my tunner log

```
Variables to adjust:
    query_cache_size (=0)
    query_cache_type (=0)
    query_cache_limit (> 1M, or use smaller result sets)
    join_buffer_size (> 256.0K, or always use indexes with JOINs)
    table_open_cache (> 1024)
    table_definition_cache(1024) > 5155 or -1 (autosizing if supported)
    performance_schema = ON enable PFS
    innodb_log_file_size should be (=1G) if possible, so InnoDB total log files size equals to 25% of buffer pool size.
```

How I said before, the query work few days ago but suddenly this no work anymore.

in other hand i have multiple wp sites and these sites suddenly come very very slow and I think it come from mysql also, because if I enter to a site without sql the site work normal.

Where I can start to check?

EDIT

its explain query

[explain query](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ySJeO.png)

Comment: This is a pretty massive query, and the place to start is by running `EXPLAIN SELECT ...` on your current select query.  See if you can identify any obvious bottlenecks.

Comment: Use `EXPLAIN` to see the query execution plan. A typical problem with performance is MySQL isn't using an appropriate index, but SQL performance goes a lot deeper than just making suitable indexes available.

Comment: i forgotten that, I updated the question with the explain query, I added it in pic because i dont know how make it as table

Comment: try executing `analyze table krakente_marketpins.bt_countries, krakente_marketpins.bus_trucks` then re-try your query.

Comment: the analyze says OK, but the query still infinite loading, I forgot mention this query work correctly in localhost with `10.1.38-MariaDB - Source distribution`

Comment: May be its taking a lot of time to download result set. Try adding `limit 5` at the end

Comment: it only need return 12 rows, in localhost finish at 0.368 sec in the server the query never finish, anyway with the limit 5 or 1.

Comment: If `pais_mercado_id IN (1...12)` is all possible cases, remove it from the `WHERE` clause.  The optimizer is not smart enough to do that for you.

Comment: pais_mercado_id can be selected from user panel

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is pretty much pseudo-code, however, I bet you can do the aggregation while passing over the data only once. Since you already have the data grouped, you don't need to subquery two more times in your select.

```
SELECT 
  BTCountry.id,
  BTCountry.name,
  BTCountry.code,
  BTCountry.last_data_from,
  BTCountry.year_last_data_from AS current_year,
  ytd =         SUM(CASE WHEN BusTruck.year_data_from = bt_countries.year_last_data_from - 1 AND bus_trucks.month_data_from <= bt_countries.month_last_data_from THEN cantidad ELSE NULL END),
  last_year =   SUM(CASE WHEN BusTruck.year_data_from = bt_countries.year_last_data_from AND bus_trucks.month_data_from <= bt_countries.month_last_data_from THEN cantidad ELSE NULL END)
FROM
  bt_countries AS BTCountry 
  INNER JOIN krakente_marketpins.bus_trucks AS BusTruck ON BusTruck.pais_mercado_id =BTCountry.id
WHERE
    pais_mercado_id IN (
    '1',
    '2',
    '3',
    '4',
    '5',
    '6',
    '7',
    '8',
    '9',
    '10',
    '11',
    '12'
  ) 
  AND mercado_id = ('1') 
GROUP 
    BYBTCountry.id,
    BTCountry.name,
    BTCountry.code,
    BTCountry.last_data_from,
    BTCountry.year_last_data_from
ORDER 
    BYytd 
DESC
```

Comment: thanks works!, I still don't understand how my query was work and suddenly the query crash!.

Comment: @hansz Please post A) SHOW CREATE TABLE bt_countries; and B) SHOW CREATE TABLE bus_trucks; and C) EXPLAIN SELECT (Ross Bush query) so we can see the improvement by reducing ROWS used for the results.  Thanks